# How many skills do you have at level 26 in Diablo 2 L.O.D.?

Tags: diablo-ii

How many skills do you have at level 26 in Diablo 2 LOD?

And also, how many stat points should you have? (to spend, if you didn't spend any)

Answer (score 5):

In each Difficulty (Normal, Nightmare, and Hell difficulty) there are 3 quests that give skill points as a reward:

- Den of Evil: +1
- Radament: +1
- Izual: +2

Plus the base 25 you gain through levelling up grants a total of 29 potential skill points. (I doubt you'll have completed these in all three difficulties at level 26)

Additionally, (while not part of the original question) there is also the quest in Act III "Lam Esen's Tome". Upon completion this will reward you with an additional 5 attribute points, bringing the count up to 130 potential attribute points.

Answer (score 1):

this depends, there are quests that reward skills and stat points, so its not exact, but assuming you haven't gotten any quest rewards yet, you should have 1 skill point and 5 stat points per level (excluding the first level).

So in your case, 25 skill points and 125 stat points.

Comment: If you add the skills gained in quests, you have 3 skills more, and if you add stat points, you have 5.
So in my case, I would have 28 skills and 130 stat points.
Also, some other interesting things (at least to me), are that you get 20 health points in a quest, and 10 points in all resistances.